# Laravel / PHP - Convert plain links in text to nice links with page title

Tags: php, laravel, domdocument

I've searched a lot but couldn't really find any relevant discussion. Here's the case at my hand -

When a user writes a blog post, they'll simply add plain links in the text. Viz. `https://somedomain.com` . Now my editor can convert these links to actual html links viz. `<a href="https://somedomain.com>https://somedomain.com</a>`.

Now I want to extract all such links in the body and convert them into links with page titles. That is, the link should get converted to `<a href="https://somedomain.com>Page Title</a>`

I've been able to extract the URLs, but the problem is that I can't find a way to fetch the page title.

```
$dom->loadHTML($request->body);
    $urls = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach($urls as $url) {
        $href = $url->getAttribute('href');
        // How do we get the title of this href, now? 
    }
```

PS: Would really appreciate if you could suggest a way to do this - or maybe refer a package that does this. I've found a package called 'ESSENCE' but that only works for media files.

Comment: Unless you know exactly who's going to use this and what you're doing I'd strongly recommend against this. a) It'll take a lot of resources, especially if there will be a lot of links b) page titles are often not as representative as you'd want them to be c) security (imagine a title having a javascript executable for example)

Comment: Lot of websites actually do this and it works pretty well. XenForo, for example converts urls into linked titles.

Comment: I don't really see a problem here, you need to fetch the relevant page (using cURL or whatever) and extract the title of the page (DOMdocument). Could be a lot of traffic depending on the count of links. You could consider using Markdown so your users have an easy way to create links (like here on SO) - users would need to enter the title of the page manually though.